# Starting synergy automatically on RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, redhat

I have a Red Had Enterprise Linux 5 and a CentOS 5 box, both of which I am trying to configure to automatically connect to a synergy server on startup. I have followed the guide at http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/autostart.html and configured them the same way I configured previous Ubuntu 7.10 boxes, and this only seems to get me half way there. Currently, synergy connects at the login screen, but once I login, it doesn't come back up.

I added the following lines to /etc/gdm/{Init,PostLogin,PreSession}/Default :

```
/usr/bin/killall synergyc
sleep 1
/usr/bin/synergyc fried-chicken # Init,PreSession only
```

All files are owned by root:root with 755 permissions, I'm just not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Synergy Autostart wiki page](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/wiki/Startup).

Comment: The simple method works, using System > Preferences > More Preferences > Sessions. In a slightly different spot, but with the same (and desired) effect.

Comment: Note: To have synergy work during the login screen, the three lines from the OP need to be added to the /etc/gdm/Init/Default file.

Comment: The /etc/gdm/Init/Default trick doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like `wall 'test'` to the script and see if that shows up on the console. if so, you know the script's being called but it's a problem with synergy. If not, the script isn't being called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add: when following Matt's advice about putting a call to /usr/bin/synergyc in /etc/gdm/Init/Default, ensure you don't use the -f option there or the script will never exit and you won't be able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following on RHEL 5.4 added to /etc/gdm/{Init,PostLogin,PreSession}/Default

```
/usr/bin/killall synergyc
while [ $(pgrep -x synergyc) ]; do sleep 0.1; done
/usr/bin/synergyc fully.qualified.hostname
```

In all cases, add the script **after** any existing script, but **before** the "exit 0".
This works for me. I think it should work as long as you use the Default X Session, if any custom Sessions are used, you will probably have to move the script to the appropriate place.