# CentOS 5.5 Gnome login screen stuck at loading

Tags: centos, gnome

I did a yum remove fontconfig not knowing that it removes all packages that depend on it as well. That's 300 packages that have been removed.

I have tried to reverse the process by running yum remove fontconfig again on another similarly-configured CentOS 5.5 machine and reinstalling those packages in the output of the command.

The Gnome logon screen is stuck at loading cursor.

My Gnome is still broken and I have switched to KDE for the time being. I can use a weird hybrid of Gnome Desktop and KDE window manager where the UI is Gnome but the desktop is not clickable and there's KDE apps instead of the Gnome ones.

/etc/sysconfig/desktop

```
DESKTOP="GNOME"
DISPLAYMANAGER="KDE"
```

Using the KDE login to choose Gnome also gives me this weird KDE/Gnome hybrid.

I have reinstalled the Gnome-related packages several times and it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

yum should have given you an indication of the volume of packages that it was going to remove and should have given you the chance to abort the attempt (unless you used `-y` which, I imagine you now realize, you shouldn't).

There's no need to attempt to "reproduce" the problem to find the list of packages. The yum log file `/var/log/yum.log` will tell you everything that yum installed and removed.

On CentOS 6 and newer yum has a `history` command that can also display this (and other) information.

Comment: The yum version in CentOS 5.5 doesn't have a history option. Didn't know about the logs, have reinstalled the stuff from when I removed fontconfig.

Gnome login is still stuck after "Setting up first time boot though.

Comment: Also the shut down icon is missing and I can't add from in the applets either. The poweroff command still works.

Comment: Bah, I thought it said `6.5` there. Not that you should still be on a `.5` of either version as that is behind for both releases. The log still has the information though.

Comment: If you added back every package you removed then things should be back to where they were (unless some internal config/etc. state got confused in the interim). You might find something useful in the output from `rpm -Va` but it might just be a lot of meaningless complaining also.

Comment: It's my work PC - CentOS 5.5 is the default distro for us as we compile stuff for RHEL 5. 

Well, actually I was trying to build the latest Synergy for RHEL 5 and it requires a newer fontconfig than the one I have. So I have installed it.

As part of getting Synergy to work I have also changed gdm config files as described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159752/starting-synergy-automatically-on-rhel-centos . These have been reverted when I reinstalled all the packages I removed. That's the only other thing I've changed besides accidentally removing fontconfig related packages.

Comment: If you've reinstalled all the removed packages (including fontconfig) and reverted the config file changes (for now) what still isn't working? What state is the system in now?

Comment: Gnome login still isn't working and Gnome desktop (when I manually choose Gnome desktop from the KDE login) isn't working. No right-click and can't launch the file explorer and KDE apps show up in the menu.

Comment: By gnome login do you mean `gdm`? That got reinstalled correct? Did you revert the config changes you made? What does `rpm -Va` output?

Comment: The log in where you put in your username and password. That's still broken. I'm using KDE login and when I choose Gnome Desktop to load after the login isn't fully functional.

Yep the config files are back to the originals - I checked the modified date.

Output from rpm -Va shows a bunch of Java packages...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B62mfc_SIxW3WnZrV2xhcE9KeVV4RXpnQmF1MG5yS2YtRXRv/view?usp=sharing