# Starting Synergy during gdm startup (greeter) in CentOS8

Tags: centos8, gdm

This is similar to [Starting synergy automatically on RHEL/CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159752/starting-synergy-automatically-on-rhel-centos/2991504#2991504)
However this doesn't seem to be working anymore.

What I basically want to do is execute a program when the greeter is shown. THis has been working before by adding it to the /etc/gdm/Init/Default script.
However right now the script doesn't seem to be called anymore (tested with a 'logger' call).

SElinux is in permissive mode. The script is executable. synergyc is specified with the full path.

Comment: I seemed to have found an alternative:

cat /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/synergyc.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Synergy Client
Exec=synergyc 192.168.1.110
#NoDisplay=true
#AutostartCondition=GSettings org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-reader-enabled
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true

Restart GDM and it works.

Comment: Note that the autostart .desktop file does not restart synergyc when you log out of your session. So it works only once after gdm service has been restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below resolves the issue. So to make synergyc always running at the GDM greeter use the PostSession script below and put the /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/synergyc.desktop file into place:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Synergy Client
Exec=synergyc 192.168.1.110
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
```

/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Kill old process
/usr/bin/killall synergyc
while [ $(pgrep -x synergyc) ]; do sleep 0.1; done

# Get the xauthority file GDM uses, setup DISPLAY var and start synergyc again
xauthfile=$(ps aux |grep Xauth | grep '^gdm' | grep -oP '\-auth \K[\w/]+')
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=${xauthfile}
/usr/bin/synergyc 192.168.1.110

exit 0
```

Comment: /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default

adding the 3 made it work for me on Ubuntu22.04 pi. Cheers